# Oracle check multiple column combination values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Here's one I've been working on for a while. I have a query which pulls data as expected...

```
SELECT a.plant,
       SUBSTR(a.completed_ts, 1, 4) wo_year,
       a.asset_nbr asset,
       c.asset_desc descr,
       c.dept dept,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.work_order_nbr)) freq,
       SUM(b.labor_hours) labor_hours
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.work_order_nbr = a.work_order_nbr
AND b.plant = a.plant,
    table_c c
WHERE a.plant = :Plant
  AND c.plant = a.plant
  AND c.asset_nbr = a.asset_nbr
  AND SUBSTR(a.completed_ts, 1, 4) = :year
GROUP BY A.PLANT,
         A.ASSET_NBR,
         C.ASSET_DESC,
         C.DEPT,
         SUBSTR(A.COMPLETED_TS, 1, 4)
```

What I need to do next is join in `table_d` to pull a rate value based on `plant` and `department` from records returned from above query.

`Table_d` has 3 columns... `plant`, `department`, and `rate`. In `table_d`, not all plant/department combinations exist, not even all plants exist. Some plants in `table_d` have a blank (' ') department value - a generic rate for the plant, for any other department.

So to pull the rate, I need something like...

- if plant and department combo found in `table_d`, pull that specific rate,
- if plant found in `table_d` but not `dept`, pull rate
   where plant exists in `table_d` with `department = ' '`
- else... if plant doesn't exist in `table_d`... set `rate` to 0

Any ideas on this?

Comment: It would be easier if you add a data sample of your tables and a desired output from that data sample. A plus would be you create an example set on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you close to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.plant,
       SUBSTR(a.completed_ts, 1, 4) wo_year,
       a.asset_nbr asset,
       c.asset_desc descr,
       c.dept dept,
       COALESCE(department_rate.RATE, plant_default_rate.RATE, 0) AS RATE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.work_order_nbr)) freq,
       SUM(b.labor_hours) labor_hours
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b
  ON b.work_order_nbr = a.work_order_nbr AND
     b.plant = a.plant
INNER JOIN table_c c
  ON c.plant = a.plant AND
     c.asset_nbr = a.asset_nbr
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_D department_rate
  ON department_rate.PLANT = a.PLANT AND
     department_rate.DEPARTMENT = c.DEPT
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM TABLE_D
                   WHERE DEPARTMENT = ' ') plant_default_rate
  ON plant_default_rate.PLANT = a.PLANT
WHERE a.plant = :Plant AND 
      SUBSTR(a.completed_ts, 1, 4) = :year
GROUP BY A.PLANT,
         A.ASSET_NBR,
         C.ASSET_DESC,
         C.DEPT,
         SUBSTR(A.COMPLETED_TS, 1, 4),
         COALESCE(department_rate.RATE, plant_default_rate.RATE, 0)
```

Best of luck.